# CSS - positioning text and icons

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm building a site and have received a PSD file with the design but am struggling on one particular section. This is how the design should look - 
[image: PSD file]

And this is where I'm at - 
[image: Coded effort]

I'm sure its pretty obvious to an experienced front-end developer but I've been using floats and display and am struggling. Here's the code I've used to get this -

**HTML**

```
 <section id="home">

        <a href="agency.html">Are you an agency?</a>
        <a href="business.html">Or a business?</a>
        <div class="container showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">
                <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
section#home {

    height: 480px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 960px;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: relative;
}

.showreel {
    height: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.showreel p  {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;


    color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;


}

.seemore {
    float: left;
}

.seeour {
    float: right;
}
```

The icons aren't exactly the same as in the design but I can change/amend later. It's more the positioning that I need to get right. Any assistance, appreciated.

UPDATE - This is how it is now. [image: Update]

Comment: are you using bootstrap or just font awesome?

Comment: Just font awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the parents and the left/right sections `flex` and use `align-items: center` to center them vertically, then use `justify-content: space-between` on the parent to separate the elements to the far edges. Then rearrange the `i` and `p` in the left element and apply a unique `margin-left` and `margin-right` to the icons to separate them from the text.

```css
section#home {
    height: 480px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 960px;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: relative;
}

.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel, .showreel > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="home">
        <a href="agency.html">Are you an agency?</a>
        <a href="business.html">Or a business?</a>
        <div class="container showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">
                <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: That's pretty much worked but on mine the 'seeour' part doesn't stretch to the right end of the container, it's almost in the centre.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead you'll need to show me if you want me to help. Otherwise all I can do is guess.

Comment: I've updated the question with a new image at the bottom.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead a picture is about as useful as your description. Show me the code. If I can't replicate it and see how you tried to integrate it, all I can do is guess.

Comment: I used your code to see it on the site. I've included the full section code above for the html and css - the rest is as you did above. I'm happy to look into this, you've offered a great amount of detail already.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I added your html and the CSS for `section#home` and it looks fine to me. Updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, no worries - appreciate you looking at this. I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead cool. if you can reproduce it for me, let me know and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/toastEater/pen/rwYRMG

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom-bar">
    <div class="showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">    
            <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 420px;
      background: url('http://i.imgur.com/5tj6S7Or.jpg') no-repeat top center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .bottom-bar{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        height: 50px;
    }
    .showreel {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .seemore,
    .seeour{
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .seeour {
        float: right;
    }
```